# Selected option of autocomplete - customisation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am using material ui autocompolete in my project. The code is as follows

```
<AsyncAutocomplete
        field={form.$("partnerId")}
        fullWidth
        fetchOptions={store.getPartners}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => (
            <div>
              <p>{option.name}</p>
              <p>{option.type}</p>
            </div>
        )})
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
        noOptionsText="Type to search"
        freeSolo={false}
        renderOption={(props, partner) => (
          <PartnerOption key={partner.id} partner={partner} {...props} />
        )}
      />
```

The selected option needs to be displayed in the following format

```
[name]

[type]
```

It should look like the attached image

[image]

I am not sure how to achieve this using the property of autocomplete. I tried the `renderInput` property but not sure how to show **name** and **type** in the textfield.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were really close.  The `getOptionLabel` signature is:

```js
function(props: object, option: Value, state: object, ownerState: object) => ReactNode
```

[(See API)](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/)

So you would need to change your `getOptionLabel` property to:

```js
getOptionLabel={(_props, option) => (
  <div>
     <p>{option.name}</p>
     <p>{option.type}</p>
  </div>
)})
```

[image: Edit Autocomplete_Render_Option]

Comment: This will not work.. This renders only the options in the described format. I want the selected option to be rendered in that way.

Comment: I am already using renderOption to render the options as you mentioned. What i need is the selected option in the described format.

Comment: Also, in the codesandbox you are not using getOptionLabel

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'll keep looking and adjust the answer if I find anything.